# Google App engine(Python) "No module named webob"

Tags: google-app-engine, sdk, google-app-engine-patch

Recently I just updated my GAE SDK version to **1.6.4**, while am trying to start my server, Its throwing **"No module named webob"** & getting exit.
Note: Am using **python2.5**
Is there any external patch or stuff needed here to resolved this issue?

If anybody faces this issue and resolved it, please guide me, how did you resolve that..

Best regards.

Comment: webob should be included with SDK. The first thing I would try is updating to the latest version of the SDK currently [1.7.0](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads) Also, what OS are you running?

Comment: Am doing development on OS Windows7. BTW have you tried 1.7.0v, is it working fine at your side.?

Comment: 1.7.0 should be fine did you run into a problem?

Comment: @KyleFinley: Thanks alot buddy, Previously i was using 1.6.1v, So if i directly move to 1.7.0v then it requires any external patch or so, to run AppEngine server?

Comment: The SDK shouldn't require a patch. It looks like you might be using AppEngine-Patch. IDK if it will cause any issues with that. The one thing I do know is that the production server is running 1.7.0 so for testing purposes you are better off doing the same.

Comment: @KyleFinley: Dear, I just updated to 1.7.0v, but still facing the same ImportError: No Module Named Webob. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to specify it in your app.yaml

See documentation here
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

Comment: Need to specify in python25 runtime as well?

Comment: Are you using django-nonrel or some other framework?  1.6.4 added a new version of webob, so I think the original is now webob_0_9

Comment: yes, am using django-nonrel framework. then should i replace this old's webob version with new version?

Comment: You need to update your django-nonrel from github.  If you don't want to update everything, you want to incorporate this change.  https://github.com/dragonx/djangoappengine/commit/257e3390ab4768abbb6d82af6c16438cb9ede3cb

Comment: previously i found the same solution, but couldn't able to apply it   :(.
BTW where do i need to keep this **boot.py**, i mean in appengine dir or in project dir?

Comment: it's in the djangoappengine folder.

Answer (score 6):

installing webob solved this for me:

```
pip install webob==1.1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

below is the exact command that resolved it for me:

```
sudo pip install webob==1.1.1
```